# Can you use Apple's mapkit for a hybrid application?

Tags: android, ios, maps, mapkit, hybrid-mobile-app

This web application is for Web and Android.  I looked into others like Google, but they have limits.

If you can use it can anyone point me to the documentation for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**2019 Update:**

Apple now has a first-party JavaScript framework for using Apple Maps on the web: [MapKit JS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkitjs).

**Original Answer:**

There is no officially supported way to use Apple Maps or MapKit on any platform but except iOS and macOS.

That said, [here is the JS source](http://cdn.apple-mapkit.com/mk/3.0.0/mapkit.js) for implementing Apple Maps on the web. Some people have been able to create working map views using it (see [fruitymaps.com](https://fruitymaps.com/))

Answer (score 0):

If you with a hybrid app means one that is built with a html/js-based framework like Ionic or a hybrid framework like Xamarin or React Native, which will all run in a native app and note solely in a browser, you could absolutely create a plugin that lets you use native map views in the hybrid view.

However, you'd probably have to do some heavy work to get the plugin to cover a basic set of features that it would then translate into equivalent MKMapView and Google Maps operations. Also, if you use a html/js-based framework like Ionic, you would have to present the map in a native view.

If you are just out for something better looking than the Google Maps web map, you could have a look at MapBox (https://www.mapbox.com/). They have a bunch of different styles and ways to incorporate their maps into apps of various types.