# Can we use iOS native map for a hybrid application?

Tags: ios, hybrid-mobile-app

Tried searching on internet and didn't found the way by which we can use iOS map in hybrid application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129034/can-you-use-apples-mapkit-for-a-hybrid-application?rq=1) it might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Well, "that depends" :) If you use a hybrid application that is purely html/js-based, you obviously can't, since native apps can't be embedded in html.

However, if you use a hybrid framework like Ionic (which uses Cordova at its core), which is html/js-based but can be extended with plugins for native functionality, you could absolutely write a plugin that uses MKMapView for iOS and Google Maps for Android.

If you'd choose to go down that path, though, you'd probably have to present the map in separate, native view (this could be handled by the plugin). You'd also have to write a wrapper that translates a single set of operations to their native equivalents.